# Xcode Lost connection to iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When running my app on device and than testing offline mode by clicking flight mode on device itself, after 3 seconds i'm getting this message:

> Restore the connection to "iPhone 6" and run "APP_NAME" again, or if
>   "APP_NAME" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug >
>   Attach to Process > APP_NAME.

- iPhone version 9.2.1
- Xcode version 7.2.1

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Debugging via the regular USB cable?

Comment: Yeah. Original iPhone cable... The funny thing is that this issue just appeared, with the same app, in the same mac with the same iPhone and all in the same version last week it worked just fine. weird.

Comment: And also, I tried to clean, remove derived data, restart Mac, restart iPhone, restart Xcode - nothing worked.

Comment: Doing a quick test, I can't seem to repeat the problem, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine that you cannot repeat the same problem, the main purpose of this post is to find someone who had the same problem and was able to fix it. Thanks anyway man!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Ok, i found workaround. Just turn off the Personal Hotspot in Settings.
For me it worked.
<3 Apple...

Comment: I didn't even notice when the "Personal Hotspot" turned itself on. I can swear it was always off. After turning it off everything works again. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks, I am facing this issue from last few days and not able to find root cause by even reviewing system logs and raising ticket for support on Apple.

Comment: Wow, worked for me as well, had the same issue in Xcode 12.5

Comment: And this still happens in 2021 - gee whizz! Thankfully this workaround still works, too.

Comment: And this still happens in 2022! See you again next year.

Comment: I have been annoyed by this forever, thank you for the workaround. I just filed a new bug in feedback assistant, guess thats all we can do.

Comment: 2023 Xcode 14.2 - still the same...

Answer (score 8):

I am experiencing the same problem. A little showstopper when trying to check the offline behavior of your App (e.g. Reachability, custom error messages etc).

**This is a known Bug** with Xcode 7 and iOS 9, already reported with Apple some month ago:
http://www.openradar.appspot.com/23021571

You were likely unable to find it because it's not called "flight mode" but "airplane mode" officially.

Comment: Crazy that such a critical core bug has still not been fixed 10 months after it was reported.

Comment: Same problem, guys. :(