# iOS app crash when running from Xcode and enabling AirPlane mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When running my app on iPhone 6 iOS 9.3.2 from Xcode 7.3.5 and 8.0 (on debug mode), then entering AirPlane mode on the app itself, it crashes with the error:

```
Restore the connection to device and run “APP_NAME” again, or if “APP_NAME” is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > APP_NAME.
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Check this stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535255/xcode-lost-connection-to-iphone

Comment: The funny thing is that I wrote the question you linked me to.. And the answer there helped me! lol